# Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

This the request I am using, it only gets the name of the place and throws as error trying to get the vicinity.

The error is

> Exception has occurred.
>   _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')"

```dart
Future<List<String>> searchNearby(String keyword) async{
    var dio = Dio();
    var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json';
    var parameters = {
      'key': myKey,
      'location': '$lat, $lng',
      'radius': '5000',
      'keyword': keyword,
      'rankBy': 'distance',
      }; 

      var response = await dio.get(url, queryParameters:parameters);
      return response.data['results']
        .map<String>((result) => result['name'].toString())
        .map<String>((result) => result['vicinity'].toString())
        .toList();
  }
```

json result:

```
    0:"geometry" -> Map (2 items)
    1:"icon" -> "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png"
    2:"id" -> "f31b24b8820ec3f5a0a37233f893f79e730fbd0d"
    3:"name" -> "PureGym Glasgow Clydebank"
    4:"opening_hours" -> Map (1 item)
    5:"photos" -> List (1 item)
    6:"place_id" -> "ChIJk1XBuqtPiEgRE_5-hxEgBW4"
    7:"plus_code" -> Map (2 items)
    8:"rating" -> 4.3
    9:"reference" -> "ChIJk1XBuqtPiEgRE_5-hxEgBW4"
    10:"scope" -> "GOOGLE"
    11:"types" -> List (4 items)
    key:"results"
    value:List (20 items)
    [0]:Map (14 items)
    12:"user_ratings_total" -> 76
    13:"vicinity" -> "11 / 12 Clydebank"
```

Comment: probably the radius 5000 should be int not string..change it from '5000' to simple 5000.

Comment: could you add `response.data['results']`json to post? I think that vicinity is number and you should change `.map<String>` to `.map<Object>`

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: says it too long to post and I cant post images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

from

```
Future<List<String>> searchNearby(String keyword) async{
```

to

```
Future<List<List<String>>> searchNearby(String keyword) async {
```

and

```
return response.data['results']
    .map<List<String>>((result) =>
        [result['name'].toString(), result['vicinity'].toString()])
    .toList();
```

Comment: Still throwing an error (Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<List<String>>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<String>>'))

Comment: Oh! I forgot! "Future<List<List<String>>> searchNearby(String keyword) async {". I editted my answer.

Comment: you are an absolute life saver!! thank you so much !!